# Extract site names from properties application pool

Tags: powershell, iis

there are 2 sites that working in one pool. Me need to extract the names of the sites for future use.
I use next command for exp.

```
PS C:\> Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\tech-2

Name                     State        Applications
----                     -----        ------------
tech-2                   Started      tech-2
                                      tech-3


PS C:\> get-item iis:\apppools\tech-2 | select Applications

Applications
------------
```

but result empty. Select with name and state working good.

Help pls.

Comment: I'm dying for an answer. This has something to do with Alias property. [Same question here](http://serverfault.com/questions/633765/unselectable-property-in-iis-powershell-module)

Comment: I'm familiar with PowerShell, but not so much IIS, so I'm not posting this as an answer unless validated: Try `(Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\tech-2).Applications`

Comment: Didn't work for me. Nothing shows. I'm thinking the `Applications` property goes back to the `ApplicationPoolSID` property. Instead of showing the SID it's showing the SIDs friendly name. It's using an alias of `Applications` for `ApplicationPoolSID` and doing and conversion.

Comment: maybe, but me need get site name on app pool from PS and use this value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following script:

```
import-module webadministration

$appPool = "MyPoolName" 

 $apps = (Get-WebConfigurationProperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[`
 @applicationPool='$appPool']" "machine/webroot/apphost" -name path).ItemXPath 

foreach ($s in $apps) {
    $name = $s -replace "\/system.applicationHost\/sites\/site\[\@name='", ""
    $name = $name -replace "' and \@id='\d{1,10}'\]\/application\[\@path='", ""
    $name = $name -replace "'\]",""
    $out += $name + "`n"
}

$out
```

The problem is that the sites are not actually stored at the application pool object, the application pool is stored at the site/application.

First I find all ItemXPaths for all the occurrences of the pool name, in the foreach loop I remove the bits we don't want. Not elegant but it works.

As a bonus, this solution gives you the site and application name, not just the site name.

Comment: I tried the script but it does not work for me. prints 2 blank lines.

Comment: ty for script. I replaced the dot on select here name path).ItemXPath and its realy work